# How to handle conditions when using the TypeState pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, types, rust

I am currently learning the TypeState pattern and came into a situation that is not covered by online examples.

Let's suppose that I have a `Connection` object with a state. The `new()` method for the object performs an authentication handshake with a remote server, and it's for this handshake that I want to use the TypeState pattern. My problem is how to handle conditions.

When performing the authentication handshake I need to send a Hello packet to which the server then responds with a list of authentication methods (no password, plain text password, md5 password).

From my understanding, the TypeState pattern always knows which state to return next. What happens when I have 3 options?

Example:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::net::TcpStream;

struct Idle;
struct NoPassword;
struct PlainTextPassword;
struct MD5Password;

struct Connection<State> {
    stream: TcpStream,
    state: PhantomData<State>,
}

impl Connection<Idle> {
    fn next(&self) -> Connection</* ??? */> {
        // How do I handle a situation where more than one state can be returned?
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like the next state should be an enum

Comment: @kmdreko Can you share an example?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html

Comment: I meant how do I use enums with the TypeState pattern.

Comment: You can create `enum AuthenticatedConnection { NoPassword(Connection<NoPassword>), PlainTextPassword(Connection<PlainTextPassword>), MD5Password(Connection<MD5Password>) }` and return an `AuthenticatedConnection` from `next()`. That way `next()` will return a value that will contain one of the three connection types, as determined at run-time. Whether this is ergonomic largely depends on what the caller needs to do with the value. Perhaps the mere fact that you need `Connection<???>` shows that typestate is _not_ a good match for your use case?

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I'm learning about the pattern and I guess I learned it's not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

As detailed by one of the comments, the TypeState pattern may not be the right choice for this situation.